# Recently updated Jquery from 1.12.0 to 3.5.1. $.When() is not called after resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, typescript, jquery-ui

```
     var DeferredObj = $.Deferred();
     startHubCallback() {
           Logger.Info("ServerHub completed : success");
           DeferredObj .resolve();
       }

      $.when(DeferredObj)
     .done((data, textStatus, jqXhr) => {
        Logger.Info("InitReview completed: success");
     })
     .fail((jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        Logger.HandleErrorMessage("InitReview completed: failed");
     })
     .always(() => {
        //hide loading overlay
        hideLoadingOverlay();
     });

     startHubCallback();
```

Before updating jquery `DeferredObj.resolve()` used to call `$.when(DeferredObj)`,  but after updating to jquery to version 3.5.1. It's not calling `$.when(DeferredObj)`.

Comment: You don't appear to ever call `startHubCallback()` which resolves the promise

Comment: @charlietfl Forget to mention calling startHubCallback(); 
The problem is after calling startHubCallback(); still $.when() is not executing.